# Tagging gone from Nautilus, GAJ, tracker

Tags: zeitgeist, gnome-activity-journal

I had installed Gnome Activity Journal, Zeitgeist and Tracker but borked the install by mixing the PPAs with the universe repos. I removed all the packages, did `apt-get remove --purge`, then did a `locate` to manually `rm` everything else.

Then I reinstalled from the PPAs properly. Now I can't tag files anymore, either in Nautilus or GAJ. What packages are involved in tagging? What else might I be missing?

Answer (score 1):

GAJ maintainer here. Since the last version (0.6) the tagging feature (powered by Tracker) has been removed from GAJ, due to problems and random crashes. For what concerns Nautilus, as far i know, installing Tracker should let you tag out of the box.

Comment: Good to know--Looks like the problem is with my tracker install, which Update Manager says has a problem. Did it from the PPAs... I'll nuke tracker then and if support for tags are gone in GAJ I'll just go to the universe repo instead of PPA on tracker.